# Distributed processing of when you cluster built with MarkLogic

Tags: marklogic

Currently, I have a cluster built with MarkLogic. 
I'm building a cluster of one from two of PC1, PC2. 
It is both windows either.

So there is a question.

Minute that was in two from a single number, I'd like to confirm that the processing speed is fast ...

Create a forest1 by creating a DB to PC1. 
I will create a forest2 to PC2.

In this case, if the advice in the reference process to forest1,2 from PC1 
Processing or will be distributed?

I do not know forest1, PC2 is whether the us play each of the reference processing forest2 to PC1.

More, thank you for your response or anyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some kinds of "Processing" are distributed and some are not.
Roughly, if your doing a "Search" and the documents are in a DB which has forests on multiple hosts then the bulk of the search processing is distributed.  Similar for storing documents - if you store 1000 documents they will be distributed among the available forests and a large chunk of the "processing" will likewise distributed.

On the other hand, if your running a non database oriented function, like say a XQuery program that calculates PI to a million digits, it will run on the host which you invoked the process and wont be distributed automatically.

Those are the extreme cases ... your application will likely fall in between with a mixture of distributed and non distributed processing, which generally works well but if you find one host is doing most of the work (most common if your application is largely functional processing not database oriented), there are ways of spreading the load.  For example the same techniques used on web servers works just as well - using a load balancer and/or proxy between MarkLogic and your requests can route request to different hosts for processing.   Internally there are ways to manually schedule processing on specific hosts.  But in general this is only beneficial if you have some specific long running "batch" type processes you want to have specific control over.   If your app is a typical "Search, Modify, Process," type application then the system will balance things well.

You can make use of the Monitoring History GUI to see in detail whats going on if you want to diagnose or fine tune for your specific needs.   Usually the easiest and most beneficial change is to use a load balancer similar type proxy application if you find unevenly distributed load.   Similarly if you are serving a the same requests frequently from static content a caching proxy can offload some of the work.

Comment: Thank you for answer.I am very happy. And translate the answers you, it takes time to understand. Please wait a little more formal reply.

Comment: Roughly, I understand your answer. 

At the same I deepened the understanding at the following URL. 
https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/cluster